# Android Image Sharing Intent -File format not supported

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-image

Data class :-

```
data class User(val imagepic: Int)
```

Passing value to recycler view :-

```
 val users = ArrayList<User>()
    val adapter = CustomAdapter(users)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
    users.add(User(R.drawable.image))
    users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
    users.add(User(R.drawable.share))
    users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
    users.add(User(R.drawable.image))
```

my shareimage function in recycler view :-

```
 fun sharepic(user: User) {
            var uri: Uri = Uri.parse(user.toString())
            Log.i(TAG, uri.toString())
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            startActivity(itemView.context, Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"), null)
        }
```

Getting error :- File format is not supported.
while checking logcat for uri , getting this - *I/ContentValues: User(imagepic=2131165295)* .

Please help on this. no idea why file format is not supported.
Let me know is there any other way to resolve this.

Comment: `user.toString()` We have no idea what value that would have. Please use a hard coded value so we know what you do.

Answer (score 0):

`sharepic()` has some problems.

First, you cannot use arbitrary strings with `Uri.parse()` and expect Android or other apps to understand it. `user.toString()` will not generate a valid `Uri` by default.

Second, you do not have a file. You have a drawable resource ID. A drawable resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the phone. There is no built-in means of sharing a drawable resource.

Third, a drawable resource is a bit arbitrary. For example, suppose that you have `res/drawable-mdpi/splash_bc.png` and `res/drawable-hdpi/splash_bc.png` and `res/drawable-xxhdpi/splash_bc.png` in your project. Which one should be shared? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Or, what if `splash_bc` is a vector drawable — what should the resolution be of the shared image? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Fourth, you are using a wildcard MIME type (`intent.type = "image/*"`). **You** are the one supplying the content — it is **your** job to tell the recipient what the MIME type is of the content.

---

The simplest solution to explain is for you to write your image to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method to get a usable `Uri` to that file, and use that `Uri` with your share logic. Also, since you know what file format you are using for your image, use that to drive your MIME type.

[This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.1/PdfProvider) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) illustrates the basic technique of using `FileProvider`. There are differences in my project from what you are trying to do:

- My content that I am copying to a file is an asset, not a drawable resource
- My content is a PDF, not a drawable
- I am using `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`

But, it illustrates the concept of copying the content to a cache file and using `FileProvider` to make it available to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for it

```
 val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, "your file")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

try {
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""))
} catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "Sorry, we cannot display this image!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show()
}
```